# Set NSTreeController with a capacity?

Tags: macos, cocoa, memory-management, nstreecontroller

In my OSX app, I'm using an `NSTreeController` to keep track of any changes to to a document. The tree controller enables versioning by acting as a source control, which means that documents can create their own branches, etc.

It works fine so far. The problem is that every change to the document adds an `NSTreeNode` to the tree. Which means that after a few hours of use, the tree has accumulated **many** nodes, which means tons of objects in memory.

Is there a way I can create an `NSTreeController` with a capacity (like you'd give to an `NSArray`) which will automatically trim child nodes? If not, what's the best way to manually flush nodes at an appropriate interval so memory usage doesn't bloat?